# Jest Enzyme testing onBlur not working with mocks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have an on Blur on an email field, that should throw an error onBlur if Validation not right.

```
function ParentComponent () {
.
.
.

    const [emailError, setError] = useState(null)

    const handleOnBlur = useCallback((target) => {
        setError(false)
        if (target.value && !target.checkValidity()) {
          setError(true)
          target.focus()
        }
      }, [setError])

return (
    <FormControl>
      <TextInputField value={emailValue} data-testid='emailField' error={emailError} type='email' length={100} onBlurAction={handleOnBlur} />
    </FormControl>
.
.
)
}

export default ParentComponent
```

I am using Enzyme to jest it

```
const mockSetEmailError = jest.fn()

  jest.mock('setError', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    useState: () => ({ setError: mockSetEmailError, emailError: false })
  }))
```

Then I render the component and try to test the on Blur

```
function wrapper (state) {
    mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])(state)
    return (
      <Provider store={mockStore}>
        <ParentComponent />
      </Provider>
    )
  }

it('calls setEmailError on Email Blur', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(wrapper(mutateSampleState(state => {
      state.loading['page'] = 'done'
    })))
    fireEvent.blur(getByTestId('emailField'))
    expect(mockSetEmailError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

I keep getting the  › encountered a declaration exception. What is the best way to test this ?

Comment: As far as i remember with Enzyme you should use imitate function to invoke elements' events

Comment: actually your test looks like you're using `react-testing-library` not `Enzyme`; also I believe your mock for `setError` does not work the way you expect